# Convert the leap year date to DateTime

Tags: c#, winforms, calendar

I'm trying to program my own calendar.
But now i have some problems with the leap years. 
I can't parse the 29th February  to datetime. Every time i want to run my code, i get the error **"String was not recognized as a valid Datetime"**.

I only get the error if i want to parse the 29th February, every other date works fine.

Here is just a small part of my code where the error occurred:

```
string day = date.Text;
string year = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
string month = tbMonat.Text;
string stringDate = day + "." + month + "." + year;
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(stringDate);
```

Does anyone know, why i get this error, and how i can fix it ?

**Edit:**

Here is the code, how i calculate if it's a leap year or not.

```
case "Februar":
          int aktuellesjahr = Int32.Parse(cbJahr.Text);
          if((aktuellesjahr % 4 == 0 && aktuellesjahr % 100 != 0) || aktuellesjahr % 400 == 0)
          {
              days = 29;
          }
          else
          {
              days = 28;
          }
          break;
```

Comment: Are you sure the year of the date you are trying to parse is a leap-year?

Comment: `string year = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();` - but... 2017 isn't a leap year...

Comment: The code by which you determine if it is a leap year, resolves 2016 to a leap year but not 2017 :)

Comment: in the edit you've added some other code, but ... it isn't clear whether you're *calling* that code - you're only calling `Convert.ToDateTime` which is a regular framework method and won't invoke the code in your edit. How does the code in the edit relate to the question? where do you invoke that? is it before or after the `Convert.ToDateTime` call?

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah i know. But I only get the error if I change the year to a leap year. Like by example 2016.

Comment: `string stringDate = "29.02.2016";
            DateTime dtdt = Convert.ToDateTime(stringDate);` works just fine. Try it by yourself. You problem is you are taking 2017 as the year.

Comment: @Pikoh Oh now i see... Stupid mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have built-in function `DateTime.IsLeapYear` that can you use here.
Try something like this:

```
string day = date.Text;
string year = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
string month = tbMonat.Text;

if (!DateTime.IsLeapYear(year()) && day == 29 && month == 2)
{
    MessageBox.Show("this is not leap year, please enter correct date"):
}
else
{
    string stringDate = day + "." + month + "." + year;
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(stringDate);
    //better to use like this, but you need to convert strings to ints
    //DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, day);
    //rest of your code...
}
```

**EDIT**: since your code is prone to many exceptions (what if user enters 32 for day, or 'a' or...), it would be better to have some method to check data before converting it to date time. Something like this:

```
private bool IsValidDate(string day, string month, string year)
{
    int i;
    //check if all those values for date/month/year can be converted to number
    if (!int.TryParse(day, out i) || !int.TryParse(day, out i) || !int.TryParse(day, out i))
        return false;

    //now check if date, written in format dd.MM.yyyy can be converted to DateTime.
    DateTime dt;
    string stringDate = day.PadLeft(2, '0') + "." + month.PadLeft(2, '0') + "." + year;
    return DateTime.TryParseExact(stringDate, "dd.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);

}
```

usage would be like this:

```
if (!IsValidDate(day, month, year))
{
    MessageBox.Show("invalid data entered");
}
```

Comment: Have a small look at my edit. I worked around the DateTime.IsLeapYear function. Because I heard the function has some faults.

Comment: IsLeapYear does year `% 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0)`. So pretty much exactly what you wanted to do in your code yourself.

Comment: @Ralf oh, okay. Good to know. I heard somewhere something about "it works with a different kind of calendar". But in this case I heard some nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to check leap-year.
Just use:

```
DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month); // return number days of a month.
```

Then

```
if(days > DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)) 
    days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month) // or show an error message
```

Comment: I really like the method you use. Although I found the problem, I will include your solution.